# tm corpus exporting some structural function words

Tags: r, tm, corpus

Using the TM Library, the corpus includes words from Vector source structure :

```
text <- readLines("some.txt")

finalCorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(newCorpus))
finalCorpus <- tm_map(finalCorpus, stripWhitespace)
save(finalCorpus, file="data/DEBUG.Rda")# DEBUG
df<- data.frame(lapply(finalCorpus, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df
>protracted periods meditation fasting prayer ennui fever energy vigor
>married joseph lee dollars million canadian dollars gbp pastored african
>american church snow hill jersey children died infancy **meta list author
>character datetimestamp list sec min hour mday mon year wday yday isdst
>description character heading character id language en origin character
>X2   X3
>1 list list**
```

The words between ** are from Corpus and not from the imported text, why I get them et how remove them (without removeWords TM function) ?